# Debugging ReactJs in Chrome on page load - this and everything else is undefined when using console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem when debugging React on initial page load. As you can see from the screenshot, if I hover over `this` I can see the content but if I use console it says that `this` is undefined. This only happens when I reload the page, if I debug when clicking around this problem does not occur. I have `React Developer Tools` for Chrome installed and noted that when this is happening it only says `Connecting to React…`. Could this be the problem?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

I'm using `.tsx` files (`.jsx` but with TypeScript) if that could matter.

Sources tab:

[image]

React tab:

[image]

Comment: How is this at all related to c#?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto BackEnd, not that it would matter.

Comment: @Ogglas, Did you ever find your way around this? This problem still persists in 2019. My best guess is there is some sort of disconnect between chrome/webpack and the source maps generated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated comments, if you launch your function from the constructor and then stop it with a breakpoint, the constructor won't finish executing, which means it won't be able to correctly set the prototype chain and most important, set the correct reference to `this`.

Comment: The code runs fine, I just cant debug it. The function is called from the constructor. No bug or exceptions, I just can't use console as the title says.

Comment: Well calling that function that performs an API call from the constructor is a BAD choice, I can tell you that. Move it to `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` and check again.

Comment: Sure but let's say I have the break point in the constructor instead of a function, then the same thing happens. My question is why console says undefined but the code works. 
From docs on componentWillMount():
`This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Ogglas think about what you're doing for a second. You're stopping execution in the middle of the constructor. Which causes the constructor function to NOT finish, which causes the `this` keyword to NOT be set and the class/component to not finish its creation. This is the reason it's a bad idea. Something goes wrong in that func and your whole component tree is dead. :)

Comment: By all means I can move the function call to `componentDidMount()` but my question still remains. Why can I see `this`-properties when hovering over, the code works but when I use console to type `this` I get `undefined`?

Comment: I have the same problem, did not figure it out yet. Have you found a fix?